# Print running commands?

Tags: linux, operating-system, widget

I am planning to make a widget or something that will show what commands the operating system is running as it is doing so, something like the Linux boot up but running in a window or widget. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You'd have to modify the program loader and create your custom version of Linux.

Comment: Can you explain how I would modify the program loader? Elaborate a bit?

Comment: The problem loader is where programs start up. In Linux it's the exec system service and its variants. You could add something to send a message to the console each time a new program starts.